# Filtering results in MySQL in join result

Tags: mysql, sql

I am beginner programmer. I have small problem with my MySQL Queries.
This is my MySQL data: https://pastebin.com/69PcBSVH

I have this tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `dishes` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `company_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `enable` char(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `dish_values` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `dishes_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `food_ingredient_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `company_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `quantity` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `food_ingredients` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `company_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `garbage` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `energy_value` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `protein` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `fat` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `available_carbohydrates` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `roughage` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `description` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `url_address` varchar(160) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `allergen` char(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `allergen1` char(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `allergen2` char(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `allergen3` char(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `available_in_demo` char(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `enable` char(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

My base is a base of dishes and ingredients needed to prepare a dish.

I need to display all dishes that are not allergens (food_ingredients.allergen = 0).

```
Table dishes = given dishes
Table dish_values = ingredients that are assigned to a given dish
Food_ingredients table = ingredients of the dish.
```

Dishes that are allergens have a value of 1 in the allergen column and those that are not allergens 0.

I make query to show my dish (without allergens):

```
SELECT 
  dishes.id, dishes.company_id, dishes.name, dishes.description, dishes.enable
FROM `dishes`  join dish_values on dish_values.dishes_id = dishes.id 
      join food_ingredients on food_ingredients.id = dish_values.food_ingredient_id 
WHERE food_ingredients.allergen = 0 
GROUP BY dishes.id
```

But it's not working correct.

As a result, I have both dishes that contain allergens and those that do not have them.

How can I repair it?

Comment: This question was here last night too. You have 1024 rows of data in your table `food_ingredients` that have a value of column `allergen` set to 0 and only few with value set to '1' so I am not sure what is it that you want to do ? If the column allergen in the table food_ingredients is the value too look and to check if some dish has allergens then your query is ok because all of your dishes do not have them. Check this fiddle : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4911d5977ac503bc0d6ed0c1143c027c and give us an example which dish should not be in the result for the last query ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `not’exists` with a correlated subquery: this avoids the need for aggregation, which is generally not good for performance on large datasets:

```
select d.*
from dishes d
where not exists (
    select 1
    from dish_values v 
    inner join food_ingredients i on i.id = v.food_ingredient_id
    where 
        v.dishes_id = d.id 
        and i.allergen = 1
)
```

For performance, you want the following index: `food_ingredients(allergen, id)`.

Side note: you should change the data type of `allergen` from `char(1)` to `tinyint(1)` since it only contains 0/1 values.

Answer (score 0):

As allergen is a char column, you need quotes around the 0. Alternatively, you can change the column to an int.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `WHERE` clause and add the condition to the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT d.id, d.company_id, d.name, d.description, d.enable
FROM dishes d 
INNER JOIN dish_values v ON v.dishes_id = d.id 
INNER JOIN food_ingredients i ON i.id = v.food_ingredient_id 
GROUP BY d.id, d.company_id, d.name, d.description, d.enable
HAVING SUM(i.allergen) = 0
```

The condition `SUM(i.allergen) = 0` makes sure that all matching rows from the table `food_ingredients` have `i.allergen = 0`.